# checking for smalldatetime column equal to GetDate() - ignoring time

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a column of smalldatetime type, date

I'd like to run a query that only retrieves rows:

where date = convert(smalldatetime,GetDate())

However, this is never finding matches as it is also comparing the times.

Ie: 01-01-2010 12:23:00 != 01-01-2010 12:25:00

How can I find matches on only the date portion?

Comment: your 'date' column is datetime as well? then you need to issue a WHERE on the date part of **both** the column and the current date. Also, IIRC, smalldatetime has a time component. Don't you just want to convert to a date instead of a datetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way which will utilize the index

```
where date >= dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
and date < dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), +1)
```

See also: [How Does Between Work With Dates In SQL Server?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql-)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
where datediff(dd, yourdate, GetDate()) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your DateTime values to Date values.  That will store only the date portion for you to compare.

A list of available Date and Time datatypes in MSSQL is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
where cast(CONVERT(char(10),DATETIME_FIELD_1,101) as datetime) 
  = cast(CONVERT(char(10),DATETIME_FIELD_2,101) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Where CAST(FLOOR(CAST([Date] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

This would make both dates appear as:

> 2010-08-05 00:00:00.000

and thus only comparing the dates ignoring the times

Answer (score 0):

found this:

```
CAST(CONVERT (CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) AS smalldatetime)
```

from here:
[reference](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/Return-only-the-date-from-a-SQL-smalldatetime-field)

this sql worked for me when I added a smalldatetime field to an existing table:

```
SELECT     testing 
FROM         LTCCAssessment
WHERE     (testing = CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) AS smalldatetime))
```